# How I can delete duplicates in a Object list by date in Kotlin with collection operators?

Tags: kotlin

I have a object list with the same id, then, i want to keep the one with the most recent date, and the delete the other with the kotlin collection operators. For Example I have :

```
{"id":111,
 "date":"02/12/2017"
 }
```

and the other

```
{"id":111,
 "date":"02/8/2018"}
```

In this case, i would like to delete the first object.

Comment: use `list.sortedBy { it.date }.firstOrNull()`

Comment: @HawkPriest what do you think that does?

Comment: that sorts the list by date (check `date.compare()` method for sortType) and `firstOrNull` gives you the element at 0 then you can clear the list after getting the firstItem or move it to a set or user `sortedList.distinctBy{ it.date }`

Comment: if all item  in the list have the same id then you can just use list.maxBy { it.date } to fetch the newest value, assuming date is save in `long` timestamp format, if the list has objects with multiple ids and you want a list with distinct id values while choosing the newest object per id, look at my answer

Comment: @HawkPriest Yes, but this is and example, imagine that you have more elements in the list...

Comment: @Roland in my last implement i didn't use operators, i used a simple foreach, but i   convinced that it is posible in some way with operators. :)

Comment: ok... added a variant that just uses `removeIf` instead of collecting the elements first...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve it like this

```
list.groupBy { it.id }.entries.map { it.value.maxBy { it.date } }
```

it will create a map of `id, List<object>` while keeping original order and then choose newest object from the list. 
Here I am assuming date is `long` value timestamp

Comment: ok thanks for the answer, i will try this, but i need to transform the date to timestamp before. However, I would then need a loop to search the map and check if something is repeated, no?

Answer (score 4):

If you really must remove the entries from the current collection the following may help you (I assume your objects (`Obj`) are contained in a list called `list`):

```
list.removeAll { anObj -> list.any { anObj.id == it.id && it.date > anObj.date } }
// or same with removeIf
```

It's probably easier just collecting what you are actually interested in and then have an immutable list in the first place.

Collecting the elements you are interested in could be done as follows (there are of course lots of other ways to do that... just one of many):

```
val result = list.groupBy { it.id }.values.mapNotNull { it.maxBy { it.date } } // mapNotNull is only used due to maxBy returning a nullable type... it isn't really needed... or well... depends on what your date type is ;-)
```

`result` will then be a `List<Obj>`. Instead of `mapNotNull` you could also use `it.maxBy { it.date }!!` if you know there is at least 1 element.

If you then still need to remove the elements from the list, you could do the following:

```
list.removeIf { it !in result }
// or
list.removeAll { it !in result }
```

However I can't really recommend that you mutate your current list just for that... The `result` in the above example already contains all the elements in the form you want (i.e. `List<Obj>`). Instead rather use the benefit of having an immutable list :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for the moment the jfawkes's answer is valid for me. However i will try your solution also.

Comment: The solutions regarding `groupBy` are very similar. The main difference between the two is: here a `List<Obj>` is returned whereas with jfawkes's answer `List<Obj?>` is returned. `}.entries.map { it.value ` is basically the same as `}.values.map {`... I just omitted the nullable type by using `mapNotNull`... you could also use `it.maxBy { it.date }!!` if you know there must be at least 1 element, which we know.